# How do I create a file list from a directory with filename, size and time length of a bunch of video files in a text format?

Tags: video, directory-listing

How do I create a file list from a directory with filename, size and time length of a bunch of video files in a text format?

I want this Windows list in a text format:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: None of the `DIR`, `ls` and `Get-ChildItem` Command(-Lets) are providing a Field for the Time Length of a Video Clip, @user2163020. The _Microsoft_ _Disk-Operating System_ `DIR` Command was not meant for that. The _Unix_ `ls` Command is even more ancient than it, when the Video Age was not that rampant as it is today. Still, there could be _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Powershell_ Command-Lets out there that are brighter than the `Get-ChildItem` Command-Let that might perform the Monkey Trick. You could search a little bit for them and see if something pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a PowerShell script:

```
$Folder = 'C:\Some\Directory'
$Output = 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.mp4 -File
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($Folder)
foreach( $File in $Files ) {
    $objFile = $objFolder.ParseName($File)
    $Name = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, 0)
    $Size = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, 1)
    $Length = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, 27)
    $Tab = [char]9
    "$Name$Tab$Size$Tab$Length" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $Output
}
```

An explanation:

1. `$Folder = 'C:\Some\Directory'` sets the directory you want to export.
2. `$Output = 'C:\path\to\output.txt'` sets the file to output to.
3. `$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.mp4 -File` gets a list of all MP4 files
4. The following retrieves the folder so we can process the files in it.

   ```
       $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
       $objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($Folder)
       $objFile = $objFolder.ParseName($File)
   ```
5. `foreach( $File in $Files )` performs the actions between `{` and `}` on each file.

   1. The following opens the file and gets the information from the columns you specified:

      ```
      $objFile = $objFolder.ParseName($File)
      $Name = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, 0)
      $Size = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, 1)
      $Length = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, 27)
      ```
   2. The following prints the information to a tab separated text file

      ```
      $Tab = [char]9
      "$Name$Tab$Size$Tab$Length" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $Output
      ```

If you want to output other columns, you can get the column ID using the PowerShell script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37061433/9882907).

Comment: Very thank you! But the output.txt is filled with only one line/finle.

Comment: @user2163020 try the update to the answer. I added a newline at the end of each line.

Comment: It's my first time on PowerShell. Manipulating the script, however, I was able to create a output for each file and then merge them on Word. I appreciate very much your script abilities. Many thanks!

Comment: I do not see any change even refreshing the browser.

Comment: I changed the explanation without changing the script. Sorry!